# Expression passes condition but ignores return statement inside the block

Tags: recursion, conditional-statements, return-value, undefined-behavior

This is a function to compare two strings recursively. It works fine as:

`compareStr("", "");` --- returns true.

`compareStr("house", "houses");` --- returns false.

But for some reason, this invocation returns undefined:

`compareStr('tomato', 'tomato');`

Even stranger is the fact that the function is making it into the code block and logging "should return true" to the console, but it's completely skipping the return statement, and returning undefined instead.

```
var compareStr = function (str1, str2) {
    if (str1 === '' && str2 === '') {
        console.log('Should return true');
        return true;
    }

    var arr1 = str1.split('');
    var arr2 = str2.split('');
    var frag1 = arr1.pop();
    var frag2 = arr2.pop();

    if (frag1 === frag2) {
        var strA = arr1.join('');
        var strB = arr2.join('');
        compareStr(strA, strB);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a return.

```
return compareStr(strA, strB);
```